# How To Use Ninject Named Bindings With DependencyResolver and PropertyInjection

Tags: c#, ninject

I realize constructor injection is preferred but I'm curious how to use Ninject's contextual 'Named Bindings' when using another form of injection.

Specifically how do I do the following when using DependencyResolver or property injection.

```
public MyService([Named("Alpha")] IRepository repository)
{
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create a named binding to work on Alpha:

```
Bind<IRepository>().To<AlphaRepository>().Named("Alpha");
```

then you can specify others like:

```
Bind<IRepository>().To<AnotherRepository>().Named("Beta");
```

When your example constructor is used you will get the AlphaRepository.

In order to use the name with a property give the property a name attribute just like you you did for the param:

```
[Inject, Named("Alpha")]
public IRepository Foo {get; set;}
```

Comment: I know how to create the named binding and I know how to use the binding with a constructor. My question is how do I use a named binding when doing injection via property injection.

Comment: Updated to answer your question